# How to run a macro in Word before save?

Tags: vba, ms-word

How to make Microsoft Word to run a VBA macro every time before any document is saved? Could it be done without adding macros into the document itself?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can subscribe to application events in `Document_Open` by using `WithEvents` variable and conventional method names (`VariableName_EventName`). Works in templates as well.

You can put this code into `ThisDocument` object, or make a separate class module as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff821218%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

```
Private WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub Document_Open()
Set App = Word.Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
MsgBox("BeforeSave")
End Sub
```

[List of all application events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dn320473%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Comment: I have tried to put this code in ThisDocument object but it still not working.

Answer (score 2):

You must add the code bits at the correct place.

> This must be at the top of your code page amongst your public variables or constant declerations

```
 Private WithEvents App As Word.Application
```

> Then add this as an open document event.

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
Set App = Word.Application
End Sub
```

> This is the event that fires on save command Ctrl+s or save icon. I added my own save format and print as I saw It most useful in the case of people filling out forms and you don't want them to overwrite the initial template.

```
Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
''save file with the saveas2 command.
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="YourDocumentNameORVariable" + _
" Date_" + Format(Now(), "yy-mm-dd"), _
FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault, _
SaveFormsData:=True
''addition to print file upon save
ActiveDocument.PrintOut Background:=True, Range:=wdPrintAllDocument, Copies:=1, Collate:=True
End Sub
```

Read more about Printout methods: [Microsoft VBA - PrintOut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.printout)

Read more about SaveAs2: [Microsoft VBA - SaveAs2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.saveas2)

Read more about FileFormat for Saving: [Microsoft VBA - FileFormat for Saving](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdsaveformat)

Answer (score -1):

try saving your file in `.xlsm`, then close, open and save it again. it should work fine.

Comment: You mean .docm ,  he's talking about a word document :)