# Auto filename when saving word document

Tags: vba

I'm a novice with VBA and fillable fields.

However here is my question:

I have created a word template which has one fillable field called "Title"

I would like to know how to proceed to have the following:

Once I open the template as a normal .doc document, and I have finished to work with it and filled in the fillable field called title
that when I click save that the document file name automatically becomes the
text that I have within the fillable field called title.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

According to this post - [How to run a macro in Word before save?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24702494/1050927), you can have your code in `BeforeSave`, cancel the save and run `SaveAs2`

```
Private WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub Document_Open()
    Set App = Word.Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox ("BeforeSave")
    Cancel = True
    ThisDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="test.docx"
End Sub
```

But beware you should check the `filename` in `DocumentBeforeSave`, if it is same as the title, you should not cancel the save.