# Change method of save in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to know if it is possible to change the way of saving a Word document.  What I want to do is have a button to save the word document which I have done successfully but if the Save button on the Ribbon or the Save\Save As option is selected a message is displayed instructing the user to save using the button on the document.  How can this be done please?

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is 'catch' the Save event by adding an event handler before save happens.

Look at this post where they ask for something similar:
[How to run a macro in Word before save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702493/how-to-run-a-macro-in-word-before-save)

It depends on you environment (Add-in, VBA, other) what exactly the eventhandler looks like but if you Google for DocumentBeforeSave you should be able to find enough examples.