# Stop save capability in a word doc

Tags: vba, ms-word

I’m wondering if there is a way to block the “save as” function (I.e. being able to change the name) of a word doc through VBA. The user should only be able to save as if they’ve filled in certain mandatory fields. I’m not sure if this is even possible as I have really found nothing on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A decent answer on how to subscribe to events can be found in this question: [How to run a macro in Word before save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702493/how-to-run-a-macro-in-word-before-save)

```
Private WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub Document_Open()
    Set App = Word.Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox ("Cancelled")
End Sub
```

This will run after you open the document

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. The message box doesn't pop up even when I get rid of the cancel command. I also get a compile error message when I just try and throw it in "this document"

Comment: hey @NicolasKlebusits, I added a screengrab. 
You will need to save the document (with the macro) then re-open it. The event registration only occurs during DocumentOpen event.